# Anchoring Web Browser control to all four sides

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, layout, alignment

I have a web browser control inside the WPF window.
The web browser should resize with the resizing of the main window. In a sense, all the four sides should be anchored with the MainWindow to be able to dynamically resize.
But unlike Windows Forms, there is not anchor property for the controls.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would set the [`Horizontal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.horizontalalignment.aspx) and [`VerticalAlignment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.verticalalignment.aspx) to `Stretch`.

The [layout system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058.aspx) and [alignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751709.aspx) references on MSDN might be of interest as well.

Also note that some containers have a properties for the aligment of their contents ([`Horizontal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.horizontalcontentalignment.aspx)/[`VerticalContentAlignment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.verticalcontentalignment.aspx)) which can be important as well.

Comment: Looks like the web browser doesn't resize with it. Will have a look at the other links as well.

Comment: @Cipher: You of course must **not** set a size as well, forgot to mention that (or set the `Width` and `Height` to `Auto`, but that should be the default)

Comment: Oh! This slight thing I didn't notice earlier. Thanks!

Comment: @Cipher: Should have guessed that this was it, things usually stretch by default if you don't change any of those properties regarding size and alignment.